# Benchmarking a lock-free stack with Java and JMH

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, benchmarking, jmh

For one of my university courses I'm required to implement a lock-free stack implementation, and perform benchmarks on it to see how it scales with respect to thread count and operation distribution. I recently discovered JMH, and figured I'd apply it to the benchmarking component of the homework assignment. I'm just not sure if I'm implementing this as elegantly as I could.

My professor wants us to measure the time it takes for 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, and 32 threads to perform 3 different distributions of operations. I've modeled that below:

```
package kylemart.multicore.assignment2;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;

// Annotations here... 
public class P1StackBenchmarks {

    @Benchmark
    public void runScenarioA(ScenarioA scenario) throws InterruptedException {
        runThreads(scenario.threads);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void runScenarioB(ScenarioB scenario) throws InterruptedException {
        runThreads(scenario.threads);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void runScenarioC(ScenarioC scenario) throws InterruptedException {
        runThreads(scenario.threads);
    }

    private void runThreads(Thread[] threads) throws InterruptedException {
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            thread.start();
        }
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            thread.join();
        }
    }

    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class BenchmarkParameters {

        @Param({"1", "2", "4", "8", "16", "32"})
        int threadCount;

        static final int iterations = 500_000;
    }

    @State(Scope.Thread)
    public static abstract class Scenario {

        Thread[] threads;
        PStack<Object> stack;
        Object object;

        @Setup(Level.Invocation)
        public void setup(BenchmarkParameters params) {
            threads = new Thread[params.threadCount];
            stack = new P1Stack<>();
            object = new Object();
            Runnable runnable = () -> {
                for (int iteration = 0; iteration < params.iterations; iteration++) {
                    operations();
                }
            };
            for (int index = 0; index < threads.length; index++) {
                threads[index] = new Thread(runnable);
            }
        }

        protected abstract void operations();
    }

    public static class ScenarioA extends Scenario {

        @Override
        protected void operations() {
            // stack.push(object);
            // ...
        }
    }

    public static class ScenarioB extends Scenario {

        @Override
        protected void operations() {
            // stack.push(object);
            // ...
        }
    }

    public static class ScenarioC extends Scenario {

        @Override
        protected void operations() {
            // stack.push(object);
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Each scenario, A, B, and C, has an `operations()` method which defines a set of stack operations with a specific frequency of `pop()`, `push()`, and `size()` calls. The abstract Scenario class is a "template" for these specific scenarios. Assuming that the annotations are inheritable (which seems to be the case -- wouldn't mind someone fact checking that though), I would expect instances of the the three concrete Scenario classes to be scoped to singular threads (i.e. `@State(Scope.Thread)`) and have its `setup()` method run before each invocation of a benchmark method (i.e. `@Setup(Level.Invocation)`). By doing this, I'm able to have the construction and setup of each scenario's threads happen before we begin running the threads.

Any issues with this implementation? Are there other facilities in JMH which would make this problem easier to tackle / implement? Thanks!

Comment: If you are asking for a review of your code, the proper site is [codereview.se]